# How to arrange category layout in CSS (mobile version)?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have created a classified ads website on WordPress, and it has category section where people can find any category listing, but on mobile version, it looks not really well and has some empty space, here's the link: https://dijubelinaja.com/categories/. How to set 3 columns for that? picture here:
[image: picture here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the width property for the ".classiera-category-new-v2-box" element and remove the flex property CSS.

Use the below CSS. Make sure you're using this for specific viewport where you want the categories to be listed in 3 columns.

```
.classiera-category-new-v2-box {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 25px;
    height: 132px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Okay, it works! Thank you so much for your information :D